# Check if two objects are of same type - Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: unit-testing, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

How to check if two objects are of same type in Dynamics AX 2012 Unit Test.

Like,

AssetProposal::construct(AssetTransType::DisposalScrap) creates an object of type AssetProposalDisposalScrap.

So I want to check if the object created by this method is of type AssetProposalDisposalScrap.

What is the best way to do this?

assertEquals?? assertSame?? Anyother?? How??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check types of two objects, the best way is to use the **is operator**.

> Simply use the assert on boolean condition **{OBJECT} is {CLASS}**

i.e.

> this.assertTrue(
>   AssetProposal::construct(AssetTransType::DisposalScrap) is
>   AssetProposalDisposalScrap );

Comment: Yes, the IS operator is the way to go. It's new of 2012 version.

Comment: Correct! And once you have asserted that it is of that type you can cast it by doing : MyClass myClass = {OBJECT} as MyClass;